# How to call Page.navigate and trigger associated Page.loadEventFired?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-headless

I am using **Chrome stable 60** (https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-2/Page/) for headless. I need to be able to do this:

1. Navigate to page 1
2. Take screenshot1
3. Navigate to page 2 (after page 1 is done)
4. Take screenshot2

However, I can't see to call `Page.navigate` twice because `Page.loadEventFired` will pick up on the latest one.

I don't want to use **Canary** because it's so unstable (screenshot doesn't even work right). So I think `Target` isn't an option (if it could be).

**What is the best way to do url navigation in serial fashion like that?**

I looked at https://github.com/LucianoGanga/simple-headless-chrome to see how they do it (`await mainTab.goTo`) but can't seem to figure out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link here https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/issues/92 gave me some idea:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');

function loadForScrot(url) {
    return new Promise(async (fulfill, reject) => {
        const tab = await CDP.New();
        const client = await CDP({tab});
        const {Page} = client;
        Page.loadEventFired(() => {
            fulfill({client, tab});
        });
        await Page.enable();
        await Page.navigate({url});
    });
}

async function process(urls) {
    try {
        const handlers = await Promise.all(urls.map(loadForScrot));
        for (const {client, tab} of handlers) {
            const {Page} = client;
            await CDP.Activate({id: tab.id});
            const filename = `/tmp/scrot_${tab.id}.png`;
            const result = await Page.captureScreenshot();
            const image = Buffer.from(result.data, 'base64');
            fs.writeFileSync(filename, image);
            console.log(filename);
            await client.close();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

process(['http://example.com',
         'http://example.com',
         'http://example.com',
         'http://example.com',
         'http://example.com',
         'http://example.com',
         'http://example.com',
         'http://example.com']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the new library from google team [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)